# Browser Compatibility issue in NVDA

Tags: google-chrome, browser, nvda

Some scenarios are working fine in Chrome whereas those are not working fine in Edge.
Am using NVDA 2019 version.

Example: In my application am getting a notification, When NVDA is turned on and am in Chrome even if my focus point is somewhere in the screen and if i get alert message the screenreader will read the alert message.
Whereas in the same scenario in Edge, the screenreader is not reading the alert even though am hovering on the alert message.It is reading the text which is behind the alert box.

Does anyone have faced similar issues? Or is this due to NVDA version ?